# Do EBS volume need to be formatted before it can be attached to a container

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-ebs

I'm wondering if one needs to format an EBS volume (e.g. via `mkfs.xfs`) before it can be used by a container running in kubernetes. I've examples where in people just create the volumes and have it mounted by kubernetes. Does kubernetes format the volume before using it first?

Comment: It depends on a particular kubernetes CSI plugin you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#awselasticblockstore):

> An `awsElasticBlockStore` volume mounts an Amazon Web Services (AWS) EBS
> Volume into your Pod. Unlike `emptyDir`, which is erased when a Pod is
> removed, the contents of an EBS volume are preserved and the volume is
> merely unmounted. This means that an **EBS volume can be pre-populated
> with data**, and that data can be "handed off" between Pods.

So it does not have to be formatted before being used.

You can find more details and [examples](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#aws-ebs-example-configuration) in the linked documentation.